# Number of times an entity is viewed

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm, jpa

1. How do you track the number of times a particular entity (say a user profile much similar to stackoverflow.com) is viewed by other users? Would it make sense to update this information when an entity is viewed using a lifecycle event like PostLoad.
2. Where would you store the number of times the entity has been viewed, would it be in the entity table itself? (Assumption: The system doesn't require you to track the users who actually viewed a particular profile)

Note: The underlying persistence engine is based on JPA/Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- createa a field (column) `profileViews`
- update the field in an UI event, not a persistence event. So whenever the page with url=`user.jsp?userId=12345` is opened, update the field. Updating it in `PostLoad` will lead to many unexpected and unwanted results. The `User` object is also loaded when the list of users is viewed, but this should not increase the number of views.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Question 1:
```

I would make a property in that entity class and increment it when ever that entity is accessed.

```
For Question 2:
```

Yes, I would store it in the same table as the entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the JPA/Hibernate, but basic logic would say:
When someone loads the view, simply update the database to viewed+1.